# Vertically aligning content of a div

Tags: css

I know this is a common question but I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious here. I'm trying to get the fontawesome icon to vertically align in the middle of the parent div, but it just keeps sitting at the top.

```js
function spinner() {
 $("#spinner").show();
}
```

```css
#spinner {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
}
 
#spinner div {
    color: yellow;
    border: 10px solid red;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div id="spinner">
     <div>
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <button type="button" onclick="spinner()">
        Spinner
    </button>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the div is hidden using `display:none` the property needs to be changed to `display:table` and then the child div should have the property `display:table-cell`.

```js
function spinner() {
    $("#spinner").css("display", "table");
 $("#spinner").show();
}
```

```css
#spinner {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
}
 
#spinner div {
    border: 10px solid red;
    color: yellow;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div id="spinner">
     <div>
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <button type="button" onclick="spinner()">
        Spinner
    </button>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll refer you to [here](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/), which explains 1) your common question and 2) how to actually vertically align. 
Summary: vertical align doesn't work the way you think it does, and you have to use other methods (easily found online) to vertically align.

You can also look into using flex-box or hacks already posted on SO.

Answer (score 0):

There is two common techniques that I know of.

1. Use the table method below.
2. Sometimes making your element to display as table creates a headache in responsive website and in that case you can use the transform:translate technique.

   #spinner div {

   position: relative; 
   }

   #spinner .fa-spinner{

   position: absolute; 
   top: 50%; 
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   }

```js
    function spinner() {
     $("#spinner").show();
    }
```

```css
 #spinner {
        display: none;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 99999;
    }
     
    #spinner div {
        color: yellow;
        border: 10px solid red;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: table; 
        width: 100%; 
    }
#spinner .fa-spinner{
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
 <html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        
        <div id="spinner">
         <div>
          <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
         </div>
        </div>
        
        <button type="button" onclick="spinner()">
            Spinner
        </button>
        
      </body>
    </html>
```